# Couldn't find <object> without an ID Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to ensure that each job has the correct link when a user clicks on it.

The issue I am having is that I keep getting the error `Couldn't find job without an ID`.

In my view I have the following code:

```
 <% @jobs.group_by{|x| x.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y")}.each do |date,jobs_on_that_date| %>
   <section class="date"><%= date %></section>
   <section id="top-job">
      <% jobs_on_that_date.each do |job| %>
   <section id="job-wrapper">
  <%= link_to url_with_protocol(@link.job_url), :target => '_blank' do %>
  <section id="job">
        <%= job.title %> - <%= job.company %>
        <%= job.salary %>
        <%= job.location %> 
        <%= job.job_type %>
  </section>
  </section>    
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </section>
  <% end %>
```

In my controller I am creating an object called `@link` as follows:

```
 def index
  @user = current_user
  @jobs = Job.where('created_at > ?', 30.days.ago).reverse
  @link = Job.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Finally I have the following Routes setup.

```
 JobappV2::Application.routes.draw do

   devise_for :users

   resources :jobs

   resources :users do
      resources :jobs
   end

   root :to => 'jobs#index'


   end
```

If I use `@link = Job.find(2)` this works but every job ends up with the link input by the job with id 2.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `params[:id]`?

I suspect that if you do `raise params[:id].inspect` in your controller, you will find it's `nil`. Besides, what's the point in creating `@link`? just put `job.job_url` in your view instead of `@link.job_url`

Comment: A good point, thanks Mike I am sure I tested that yesterday and it didn't work but seems to have now :)